# How to convert System.Data.Linq.Binary to a Stream?

Tags: .net, linq, streaming

Thought I could use the BinaryWriter but haven't had any luck.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need an instance of a Stream derived class to provide the Stream implementation.  MemoryStream is the ticket:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(bin.ToArray());
```

where "bin" is your Binary instance.